# Check if file uploaded is a video and get it first image

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
<input type="file" name="comment_file" class="comment_file">
  <img src="" class="show_img">

  $(document).on("change", ".comment_file", function(evt) {
    var $source = $('.show_img');
    $source[0].src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
  });
```

I want to preview the file uploaded when user selects a file.
If a user select an image, the code above will display the preview of that image in the `<img>` tag.

But if the user selects a video, nothing is shown in the `<img>` tag.

I would like to know how I could check if the file uploaded is a video and how to get the first image of that video to be displayed in the `<img>` tag ?

thanks.

Comment: Might be useful to you: http://usefulangle.com/post/46/javascript-get-video-thumbnail-image-jpeg-png

Comment: Well the file type is on the file object which can be obtained easily but not sure about the thumb part. You could always create a generic thumb for video format